# VS2015: Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "...\csc" is invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

VS2015 update 3 build C# DLL libraries, I got below error immediately:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc" is invalid.

Could anyone help a suggestion please? I search a lot, but didn't find the root cause yet.
I can build this same project with VS2019. The Targeting framework of the project is to .NET Framework 4.6.1. and I have a configuration  csc in the csproj file.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: from the menu, try Build, Clean Solution

Comment: .NET version isn't related to Visual Studio version. App targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 can be built using Visual Studio 2019 as well. _I have a configuration csc in the csproj file_ Please, share what do you have, your question isn't fully clear at the moment